# Using CTE to form loop in databricks

Tags: sql, databricks-sql

I have to run this loop 20 times OR more based on conditions/data (last `CTE = H20`). Trying to find a way to recursively run the loop based on newly formed CTE in DATABRICKS `SQL`.

```sql
With H as (
    SELECT ..... ;
    )
, H1 as (
    SELECT ....  FROM H .. ;
        )
, H2 as (
    SELECT ....  FROM H1 .. ;
        )
, H_ALL as (
    SELECT * from H1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * from H2
    UNION All
    SELECT * FROM H3
    TILL H20
    )
SELECT * FROM H_ALL
```

Comment: do you have to use sql or is it fine to use scala ? reason if it is sql you have to write sql manually where as if it is scala or python you can do loop.

Comment: Why don’t you just UNION in a single statement? What benefit are you getting by selecting in CTEs and then UNIONing?

Comment: Using CTE's because data is brought into each CTE with some conditions/ further conditions added into child CTE's....  May be we can try python with databricks notebook, however trying to see if it can be achieved in SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
case class Catalog(database: String, tableName: String)
val database = ""

spark
  .sql(s"SHOW TABLES FROM ${database}")
  .select($"database", $"tableName")
  .filter($"tableName" rlike "h[1-9]") // condition to select all tables where each table startswith h1,h2 .. etc ..
  .as[Catalog]
  .collect
  .par
  .map { catalog =>
    spark.sql(s"SELECT * FROM ${catalog.database}.${catalog.tableName}")
  }
  .reduce(_.unionAll(_))
  .show(false)
```

Comment: Thank you s.polam.  How can this be done in python loop ?